# Error when trying to color and underline

Tags: color, soul, underline

Here is my piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\tt\
\ul{{\color{red}text}}.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

This simple piece of code generates a word "text" in red with an underline. However, if you just add a space after the word "text" or a space followed by a word, like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\tt\
\ul{{\color{red}text text}}.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

it will generate an error like

```
! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

See the soul package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.9 \ul{{\color{red}text text}}
                               .
```

Can somebody tell me why is that? How can I do both color and underline but I can control the color of the underline?

Comment: Try `{\color{red}text} text` inside `\ul`

Comment: ... and don't use the deprecated `\tt` command.

Comment: Your code compiles without problem, but it's clear that your example code differs from the error.

Comment: Can you fix your code to replicate the error? Otherwise this question is unclear.

Comment: I just added the piece that generates the error message.

Answer (score 4):

Grouping with `\textcolor` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\ttfamily
\ul{{\textcolor{red}{text}}}.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The color of the underline can be controlled with `\setulcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
\ttfamily
\setulcolor{cyan}
\ul{{\color{red}text}}.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or rewritten to move the color command out of `\ul`'s argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  \ttfamily
  \setulcolor{cyan}%
  \textcolor{red}{\ul{text}}.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case it also works using `\ul{{\color{red}text}}`...